# openpyxl How to set cell to 'ignore error'?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm setting a row of cells to a formula like:

```
TweleveWeekRollingFormula = "=AVERAGE(B" + str(ExcelRowNumber + 20) + ":B" + str(ExcelRowNumber + 31) + ")"
```

This works fine but causes excel to display a small green triangle in the cells top left corner:
[image: Error Displayed in Excel]

I can clear the error manually in excel by clicking on the cells popup menu (!) and selecting 'Ignore Error'.
Is there a way to do this with openpyxl? (and not display the green triangle)

Comment: This is what excel does to the xml:
[code]<ignoredErrors><ignoredError sqref="B34" formulaRange="1"/></ignoredErrors>[code]

Comment: The context is incomplete but the cells popup menu is a tooltip in Excel and nothing to do with the OOXML file format. But it is possible that there's a global setting somewhere.

Comment: The ignoredErrors tag is at the end of the worksheet tag:
[code]<pageMargins left="0.75" right="0.75" top="1" bottom="1" header="0.5" footer="0.5"/><ignoredErrors><ignoredError sqref="B34" formulaRange="1"/></ignoredErrors><drawing r:id="rId1"/></worksheet>[code]
Does that make it a global setting?

Comment: See §18.3.1.50 of the OOXML spec. "This is simply a guess by the implementing application, and a recommendation to the user." Would accept a PR for this but not desperate for it.

Answer (score -1):

Those numbers are strings. The way you are going to make this go away *as well as ensure that you won't have calculation errors* is by setting those number values to floats (since you want decimals). They are being entered in as strings. You don't want that. The only reason why it works fine now is because Excel converts those string to numbers for the formula successfully.